# Javascript delay on audio play on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, html5-audio

I want to build a Simon Game.
I want to play a sound on click but the sound has a noticeable delay(4/5 sec).
How can i prevent it and play the sound exactly on click ?

Here the code:

```js
var blue = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3");
$(".but").on('click', function(){
    blue.play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="but">Play</button>
```

Comment: When I run the snippet, there's no delay.

Comment: maybe slow connection issues?

Comment: I don't have a delay...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't hear a delay. Try the snippet below or this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/JyagZa)**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var blue = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3");
  $(".but").on("click", function() {
    blue.play();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="but">click for sound</button>
```